# Excel Interop - Stop Chart from resizing with rows and columns

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

What is the correct property to use to stop Excel from resizing the chart when resizing columns and rows?

This is what I'm looking for https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1823-excel-prevent-chart-resizing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Placement property:

```
   excelChart.Placement = xlMove
```

I just want to put this here for future use.

If you want to know the properties of methods to call to manipulate Excel/Word via Interop.

1. In Excel/Word, enable the developer toolbar on the ribbon.
2. Click **Record Macro**
3. Do whatever you want to do programmatically, but do it via the Excel/Word UI.
4. Click **Stop Recording**
5. Click **Macros->Edit** (Opens VBA)
6. View the code for the macro you recorded. It will be in VBA, but you will be able to easily port in to C# or VB.

Comment: Thanks! It's a shape property, to be exact: `objShape.Placement = XlPlacement.xlMove;`

Comment: Cool. It seems to work for any `Shape` & `Chart` inherits from `Shape`